# Tweaking \theoremstyle

Tags: indentation, theorems

Well I want to do is when LaTeX writes **Theorem** at the new line instead of the left side of the page it be a little indented. In other words I want it to start from a little bit to the right.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ntheorem` package.

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\setlength\theoremindent{\parindent}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

Now the `thm` environment will be indented the same amount as a paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/etoolbox.html) and the `addmargin` environment of the `scrextend` package (which is included in [KOMA-script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\pretocmd{\theorem}{\bigskip\begin{addmargin}[1.5em]{0pt}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\endtheorem}{\end{addmargin}\bigskip}{}{}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{theorem}
\blindtext
\end{theorem}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add `\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}` to compile without errors.

Comment: There is also a `marginbox` environment from the `adjustbox` package (starting from 2011/08/13), which could also be used here.

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution here, maybe not the best. If you are happy with it, you may want to control the indentation with the line

```
\def\theoremframecommand{{\hspace{10pt}}}
```

minimal exmaple is:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\setlength\theorempreskipamount{0pt}
\setlength\theorempostskipamount{-3pt}
\def\theoremframecommand{{\hspace{10pt}}}
\newshadedtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\section{chapter 1}
\section{section 1}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{Theorem}[Theorem 1]
\lipsum[5]
\end{Theorem}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it seems that there is no easy way to remove the automatic indentation of the text coming just after the theorem

Comment: Do you looking for something like this: `\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@endtheorem{\@afterheading}
\makeatother`

Comment: it looks like the indentation is still there after a theorem with your suggestion?

Comment: You mean the indention after `end{Theorem}`. Yes with the code above I get no indention.

Comment: I think I will have to try with a minimal example. On the file I tried, it did not change anything.

Comment: I answered to present code.

Comment: yes, I understand. That's why I need to try again. Thank you